# Presenting NavigationalViewController in TabbarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'm developing an iOS application and structure is tab bar based. My root view controller is TabBarController but I need to present a navigational view controller in the beginning of the application if app is launched for the first time. I implemented a FlowViewController to control flow of the application. In FlowViewController, I create TabBarController and assign it as a rootviewcontroller.

How can I present a navigational view controller in the beginning of application and then present TabBarController.

FlowViewController

```
TabBarViewController *rootVC = [[TabBarViewController alloc] init];
rootVC.delegate = self;
rootVC.tabBar.translucent = NO;
self.rootViewController = rootVC;
```

In AppDelegate, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
self.flowController = [[FlowController alloc] init];

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[ [UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.window.rootViewController = self.flowController.rootViewController;

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Answer (score 0):

If a setup screen is needed in an app normally I will use NSUserDefaults to check whether the app has been launched before in `viewDidLoad()`. If not then I will present the setup viewController. Once the user has completed the setup process add the something to NSUserDefaults so when the app is launched it knows the user has been through the process already.

Answer (score 0):

In my application, I have set UINavigationController as root view controller. Then I have added the TabBarController as child of UINavigationController.

[image]

Design the view controllers in StoryBoard, as you want. Set Storyboard id for UITabBarController and call tab bar controller using that storyboard identifier.

-(IBAction)LoginAction:(id)sender{

```
UITabBarController *loadTabBar = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabBarViewControllerID"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:loadTabBar animated:YES];
```

}